# Custom "Insert into Post" button

Tags: uploads, media-library

I am trying to make a simple plugin that sets a background image. I have it linked to the media library so that when you click "Insert into Post" it does a custom function. However, obviously this custom function is undesirable in any other context. As such I would like to make a separate button "Make Background" that would call the custom function. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to show up in the image edit, say next to "insert into post" you will need to hook into

```
attachment_fields_to_edit 
//for instance
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'yourfunction', 1, 2 );
```

Have a look at media.php
http://mobile.adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/attachment_fields_to_edit?version=3.1&file=wp-admin/includes/media.php

Comment: Ok cool, looks promising, so 'yourfunction' would just echo a html button? And how could I get that button to do something? With the "Insert into Post" I can just hook into it's default function to do my own thing.

Comment: the yourfunction could be any function or functions really, I just used that as an example.